# How do you exclude a basic type property of a persistent object from being persistent?

Tags: python, persistent, zodb

For example if the type is an int or a str property of an object, how would you exclude it in the object's class. Is it like you have to declare a decorator before the property, what is it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Persistent Rules:](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/ZODBPersistentComponents.html#persistent-rules)

> - Your objects, and their attributes, must be “pickleable”.
> - Your object    cannot have any attributes that begin with ‘*p*’.
> - **Attributes of your    object that begin with `_v_` are “volatile” and are not saved to the    database** (see next section).
> - You must explicitly signal any changes    made to mutable attributes (such as instances, lists, and    dictionaries) or use
>     persistent versions of mutable objects, like
>     ‘ZODB.PersistentMapping’
>
> The third rule is that all object attributes that begin with `_v_` are
>   “volatile” and are not saved to the database. This means that as long
>   as the persistent object is in Zope memory cache, volatile attributes
>   can be used. When the object is deactivated (removed from memory)
>   volatile attributes are thrown away.
>
> Volatile attributes are useful for data that is good to cache for a
>   while but can often be thrown away and easily recreated. File
>   connections, cached calculations, rendered templates, all of these
>   kinds of things are useful applications of volatile attributes. You
>   must exercise care when using volatile attributes. Since you have
>   little control over when your objects are moved in and out of memory,
>   you never know when your volatile attributes may disappear.